# Можно ли в Visual Studio кликнув на переменную перейти в место ее инициализации?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Можно ли в Visual Studio кликнув на переменную, функцию перейти в место ее инициализации, например как в QT ? Если да то какое сочетание клавиш + клик?

Comment: Можно ПКМ и выбрать Go To Definition вроде.

Comment: С каких это пор так в QT можно?

Comment: Да все время, вроде можно было ctrl+click жмешь и проваливаешься или свою или библиотечную

Comment: А вы случаем не путаете инициализацию с чем-то другим, например с объявлением или определением?

Comment: Нашел F12 и ctrl+F12 надо было меню читать спс Beginner